# Can I group methods in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I'm starting with Meteor, and want to organize my methods... 
By example, I have 2 collecations: 'a' and 'b', both have the insert method.. I want to do something like that:

```
Meteor.methods({
    a: {
        insert : function(){
           console.log("insert in Collection a");
        }
      },
    b: {
        insert : function(){
           console.log("insert in Collection b");
        }
      }
});
```

And then call
`Meteor.call('a.insert');`

It's possible to do this? Or how can I organize my methods?

I don't wanna make methods like: 'insertA' and 'insertB'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this syntax :

```
Meteor.methods({
  "a.insert": function(){
    console.log("insert in Collection a");
  }
  "b.insert": function(){
    console.log("insert in Collection b");
  }
});
```

Which allows you to do `Meteor.call("a.insert");`.

Comment: This is the style we currently use at Edthena. I've also seen `a/insert` to be more like a URL. It's just a matter of preference.

Comment: this is what I do as well, it's pretty convenient. Also you can have multiple meteor method hooks and they'll keep on extending

Answer (score 5):

Building on saimeunt's idea, you could also add a helper function to your code if you are concerned with the elegance of these groups in your code. Then you can use the notation you liked and even nest groups arbitrarily:

```
var methods = {
    a: {
        insert : function(){
           console.log("insert in Collection a");
        }
    },
    b: {
        insert : function(){
           console.log("insert in Collection b");
        },
        b2: {
            other2: function() {
                console.log("other2");
            },
            other3: function() {
                console.log("other3");
            }
        }
    },
};

function flatten(x, prefix, agg) {
    if (typeof(x) == "function") {
        agg[prefix] = x;
    } else {
        // x is a (sub-)group
        _.each(x, function(sub, name) {
            flatten(sub, prefix + (prefix.length > 0 ? "." : "") + name, agg);
        });
    }
    return agg;
}

Meteor.methods(flatten(methods, "", {}));
```

You would then call with the dot notation, like:

```
Meteor.call('b.b2.other2');
```